# Convert .Net 2.0 project to .Net 4.7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Looking forward to leverage .Net 2.0 MVC project structure especially `wwwroot` folder features etc. Not sure why MS provides project template updates only for .Net Core.

What is best way to convert newly created .Net Core 2.0 project to Full Framework say .Net 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove all nuget packages from project
2. Right click the project in Visual Studio 2017 and edit the .csproj file
3. Replace the target framework:

`<PropertyGroup><TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup>`

4. Remove any used tools from csproj file
5. Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore` nuget package
6. Add your required nuget packages via nuget package manager (or if you know their names by editing the csproj file directly)

You might get some errors concerning nuget packages on compiling. Those will vanish if you let visual studio reinstall those packages or by hitting `dotnet restore`